# Is there a reason why legit web sites using this type of obfuscation

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Saw some top 200 web sites (by Alexa) using obfuscation in the javascript code.  Wonder why.

**youtube**
[image]

**Booking.com**
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE1**
   Changed the title so it makes a little more sense.  I have a hunch that it's done to prevent data scraping, not sure it's agreed by the community.

Comment: There's a reasonable question here - "Why would you avoid using a string with <script> tag in client-side JS?" - but you've buried it in the screenshots and need to make it more explicit if you want to get answers.

Comment: Thanks @nrabinowitz for the idea. While obfuscating "<script>" is one of the obfuscation observed here, I saw youtube obfuscated "src=" tag.

Comment: i din't think it's opinion based, but you may try security.stackexchange.com, they are more suited to tell you why it has been obfuscated like this if it has anything really relevant against scrapping and so on. By the way, on SE sites, image of written text are not welcome since the link may disapear after, you should copy and paste the code.

Comment: Thanks @Walfrat, I will post it there then.